# What is node, node.next and node.next.next in linked-list.?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am just curious about node . node.next and node.next. Until now we have read that node has two part in which it store data and address of next node(node.next) then whats about node.next.next. ? Where the address of node.next.next will be stored. I just implemented node.next.next to delete a number from the end of list. Its working well. Butt i don't know about node.next.next?? please help me in understanding of concept of nodes.
Here is code in which i implemented node.next.next.

```
public void del_`enter code here`end(){
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp.next.next!=null ){
            temp= temp.next;
        }
        temp.next= null;

}
```

Comment: Are you asking what `next.next` means?

Comment: yes i am asking about next.next.?

Answer (score 7):

node = current node

node.next = next node to current

node.next.next = 2nd node from current node

[image]

little more explanation about how's your logic work

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have got my answer. My question is that either Null is also a node or not??? Actually i want to say that my last node has a address of none, does it mean that there is also a node which is null???

Comment: @HassaanMalik yes there will be null because in the example next pointer of node 4 is type of `Node` and by default every object type in java has a default value of `null`